# Dock "extension" on OS X

Tags: osx, launcher

I'm trying to make my Dock on my Mac a bit smaller. I'm looking for something similar to Chrome's (removed) App Launcher, but for OS X apps.

I'm on OS X El Capitan, and would prefer it to be free. If the application is closed source that's okay, but I would prefer it to be open source.

Chrome's App Launcher (not my screenshot):

[image: Chrome App Launcher screenshot]

Comment: Not open source & not free, so not posting as an answer - but [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html) is similar, massively customisable & can be anchored anywhere [just not in the Dock itself] No affiliation but I've actually been using it daily since v1 in the 90s. Wouldn't be without it.

Comment: @Tetsujin It occurred to me that I never replied. Thanks for the recommendation, but after several days of use it didn't work out as I had hoped. Thank you though!